# Updating a column with Auto increment ID based on update of another column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, database-trigger, invoice

I have a MySQL table in the following format where column A is always updated with now() so the updates are always in time ascending order.

```
Column A (Datetime)             Column B (varchar)
NULL                            NULL
NULL                            NULL
NULL                            NULL
```

Now whenever column A is UPDATED, column B should have an auto increment ID generated from the last value and updated as well.

```
Column A                        Column B
NULL                            NULL  
23-12-2018                      1
NULL                            NULL
```

and then

```
Column A                        Column B
01-01-2019                      2  
23-12-2018                      1
NULL                            NULL
NULL                            NULL
```

and so on..

Is there a way to do this?

Also, I have heard that auto increment IDs may be skipped in case of failures.

Since this is for invoice generation, I cannot take the chance that ids maybe skipped.

Edit: These are simple columns and do not contain the primary id which is ofcourse an auto increment unique id. I have excluded the primary key column here.

The purpose is to have a draft order created in the database and when its fulfilled, then generate a unique incremental order id with no skips.

Comment: An autoincrementing id should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database. Create the invoice number via some other process. The invoice number and the primary key can (and in my view, should) be two different things

Comment: Also, your initial assumption is simply incorrect.

Comment: Initially when you insert the row in the table, it will have an autoincremented ID (as primary key). Then, when the user finally converts the draft invoice into a completed one - you will lock the table, set the invoice number as `COALESCE(MAX(invoice_number),0) + 1` and then unlock the table.

Comment: *where column A is always updated with now()* What method is used? auto-utilizing? trigger? *whenever column A is UPDATED, column B should have* Does the column B value must NOT be incremented when the row is updated but the value for column A is not changed (some another column is changed only)? If the row in the last table with column A = `23-12-2018` is updated to some another value does its column B value must be updated to 3? or it must be updated to 2, and the value in the row where A value is `01-01-2019` must be updated to B = 1?

Comment: @Strawberry there was no mention of primary key, hence not treating it as the same thing. But anyways, modified the question to prevent this confusion in the future.

Comment: Without the PK column, the question really doesn't make sense. Remember that rows in relational database tables represent unordered sets.